# Does "width" overwrite "padding"?

Tags: css

Let's say the width of the containing box is 5cm, padding(all sides) is 2cm.

if I set the width of the content to be 50%. Now the absolute value of the width would be 2.5 cm. But if the padding effect is still there, then the box now would be 2+2.5+2 = 6.5cm. But the content would no longer be 50% of width now(2.5/6.5 != 50%).

I'm kinda confused,any help? Thanks!

Comment: [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) to understand how this currently works.

It does vary significantly between some browsers (especially older ones).
Not as big a problem as it used to be, but the solution to use `box-sizing` may not be a universal fix depending on your users (any hold-outs still on IE >8?).

As stated by others you can use the [`box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to fit either to the content alone, content with padding, or the entire box w/padding & border (which is probably what you want).

Answer (score 3):

The result is correct. To simplify these calculations you could use `box-sizing: border-box` to include padding in total width.

> border-box
>
> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer
> when the document is in Quirks mode. Note: Padding & border will be
> inside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border:
> 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width:
> 350px;}

Reference: [MDN - box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem devs come across.

If I have:

```
<div style="width: 200px"></div>
```

Then the width will be 200px wide.
If I add 10px padding, then I need to deduct 20px total from the width.
So to keep it 200px wide it must now be:

```
<div style="width: 180px; padding: 10px"></div>
```

It is possible to override this so the width doesn't need to be adjusted according to padding, but I feel you should stay true to CSS's intended way of working.

Answer (score 2):

> With does not override padding, the padding is added to the width.
>   Think of padding as extra width but outside of the element.
>
> The width will not override the padding but the padding will still be
>   there so other elements will be pushed away from their position (if
>   relative).

Edit: Confused padding with margin.

Comment: so, you mean padding comes out of the border of the element?